# Restrict form input to a single numeral

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to restrict an input to typed numbers, but with at most one numeral.  e.g. '0', '1', '2', '9', but not '12' or '99'.

My problem is I can enter any amount of number in my current code.

The current code I am using is reproduced below.  [Here is a JSFiddle where you can test it.](http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/88/)

```
$('.numbersOnly').keypress(function(e) {
            var verified = (e.which == 8 || e.which == undefined || e.which == 0) ? null : String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[^0-9]/);
            if (verified) {e.preventDefault();}
    });
```

Comment: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#inputmask - might help (or a similar plugin)

Comment: What exactly is the desired format of input?

Comment: Still unclear. Is “9.” OK? What about “.9”? If you only want to allow numbers 0 to 9, please say it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think about:

```
$('.numbersOnly').keypress(function(e) {
            var allowed = /[^0-9]/;
            if (!/\./.test($(this).val())) allowed = /[^0-9\.]/;

            var verified = (e.which == 8 || e.which == undefined || e.which == 0) ? null : String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(allowed);
            if (verified) {e.preventDefault();}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an input element with type="number", it has pretty good support (http://caniuse.com/input-number) and makes validation a built in browser feature that does not require javascript (except as a backup).

```
<form>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="9">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/cxb8W/7/